# Identifying hidden calls to copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was testing some code of mine dealing with nodes by putting some printouts in the constructors and destructors, and I realized the **there is 3 hidden calls to copy constructor** happening. However, looking at the code, **I can only identify why 2 hidden calls would be happening, but not for the third**.

Every `Node` has its identifying level, and some other data. I have a kind-of-Singleton class, in a sense that it is possible to create, and later use a reference to, a singleton `dummy` *for every distinct level*. The code is as follows:

```
class Node{
   public:
   Node(...) {
      myNumber = Node::counter++;
      std::cout << "constructing Node: " << myNumber << std::endl;
      ... 
   } // normal constructor
   ~Node() { 
      std::cout << "deleting Node: " << myNumber << std::endl;
   }
   static Node &dummy(int level);

   private:
   static int counter;
   int myNumber;
   bool isDummy;
   static std::map<int, Node> dummies;     
   Node(int level) { 
      myNumber = Node::counter++;
      std::cout << "constructing dNode: " << myNumber << std::endl;
      ..
   } // private constructor, just for dummies
};

int Node::counter = 0;    
Node& Node::dummy(int level){
   std::map<int, Node>::iterator it;
   if ((it=Node::dummies.find(level)) == Node::dummies.end()){
      // no previous dummy present at this level
      it = Node::dummies.insert(std::make_pair(level, Node(level))).first;
      // this line invokes 3 HIDDEN CALLS TO COPY CONSTRUCTOR
   }
   return it->second;
}
```

Then, at some point in my (user) code I call:

```
Node &myDummy5 = Node::dummy(5);
std::cout << "have dummy!" << std::endl;
```

The output I get when this is the only user code is:

```
constructing dNode: 0
deleting Node: 0
deleting Node: 0
deleting Node: 0
have dummy!
deleting Node: 0
```

I realize from my output that there is 3 hidden calls to copy constructor happening (because if the `Node` was constructed differently, it would have a different `myNumber`, and also, all of "my" constructors print an output).

Could you please help me **why all 3 hidden calls are happening**? I can guess for 2/3 that the reasons are:

- copying of `Node` when `std::make_pair` is called
- copying of that `pair` (and subsequently, the `Node` which is `second`) when doing `insert`
- ??? <sub><sup>I have no idea what the 3rd call might be</sup></sub>

Sorry if there is any errors in the code, this is actually a part of a much larger project, and I have tried to just put a minimal piece of code up as an example. I will try correct any if spotted.

Comment: It all depends on the implementation of `std::map`, of which we know nothing about. It could be because of the sorting made by `std::map`, or it could be something completely different.

Comment: What's the compiler and did you compile in C++03 or C++11 mode?

Comment: @T.C. I'm using C++03 still.

Answer (score 0):

All STL container use copy semantics to manage their objects.  That's why it's a precondition that your class supports copy construction and copy assignment before you may use it with STL containers.  So under the hood, `std::map` is using copy to organise your object.  That's all we know, it's implementation dependant *how many times* it'll copy your object for a give task.